# how to NAME a string-array using a string resource

Tags: android, string, resources, arrays

How can I do this?

```
<string-array name="@string/a_string_from_resources">
```

Is it possible to name a string-array using a string Resource?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<resources>  
    <string-array name="@string/a_string_from_resources">  
        <item>first</item>  
        <item>second</item>  
        <item>third</item>  
        <item>fourth</item>  
        <item>fifth</item>  
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: @awoodland - my query is pretty well understandable about what i want to know here. i am seeking for a constructive answer to my query

Comment: sorry, I shouldn't have phrased it like that. I was trying to show that I think the excessive question marks lower the quality of an otherwise perfectly good question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<string-array name="array_name">
```

Comment: that's just giving a string as a name.... i want to pull an existing string from the resources which i have defined to be used as a name for this string-array.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. String may differ according to configuration changes. And resource name must be the same for all configurations.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you cant! Because the R.java is generated from all the resources at the same time. As the xmls are meaningless before generating, resource files wont be able to gather the resources from themselves.